# Закрыть сайт, вход только после авторизации

Tags: php, авторизация

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать так, чтобы пользователь который не авторизовался на сайте не смог увидеть его содержимое, по примеру: http://portal.omr.odessa.ua/login
Используется движок KVS, написаный с помощью шаблонизатора Smarty.
Уже авторизация сама готова, так же проверка правильно ли все введено, потом которая редиректит на сайт. Осталось закрыть страницы и реализовать проверку на станицах сайта, что пользователь действительно авторизован.

Comment: `Уже авторизация сама готова` как то не особо с вопросом сочетается. Что делаете при авторизации? сессию, токен? Без этого авторизация не авторизация

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, просмотрите пожалуйста мои файлы на авторизацию [ссылка](http://rgho.st/85jfKxkbH)

Comment: Не авторизация, а аутентификация видимо?

Comment: Очередной сайт с видеопорно?  ;) С чем выбор связан такой специфичный CMS?

Comment: Очередной) Она как раз подходит для данной тематики. 
Нужно реализовать хоть что-то, лижбы закрыть сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как там в этих хипстерских движках, но на нативном PHP, (а если до этого не писал, то лучше сначала именно самому на голом PHP хоть что-то создать работающее)
1. При входе на сайт пишем в сессию нечто подобное:

```
$_SESSION['login']=true;
```

2. На каждой странице проверяем:

   `if(!$_SESSION['login'])
       {
       header('location:/index.php'); //переадресация на страницу входа
       exit();
       }`

естественно, session_start(); не забываем

Comment: 1. При входе на сайт пишем в сессию нечто подобное:
Писать в самих страницах сайта?

естественно, session_start(); не забываем -- это куда нужно писать?
Извините, но я в этом деле нуб(

Comment: Я совершенно не знаком с готовыми движками, и разбираться желания нет, если честно, возможно на KVS единственный роутер (единая точка входа), тогда лишь несколько строчек в одном фйле, (приложите минимум усилий, покурите php.net). Но исходя из соображений "не навреди" могу лишь посоветовать обртится к разработчикам - они на сайте обещют техподдержку, или на fl.ru

Comment: Уже пробовал единую точку (проект типо видеохостинга, берут другие видео) когда человек взял видео к себе, то если сделать единую точку входа, видео не отображается (просит пароль). Поэтому только логинизация.
В движке есть файл, если туда вписать PHP код, то это отобразится на всех страницах. 
Или если хочется свой код вставить то используется {{PHP}} {{/PHP}}

Answer (score 0):

Поставь в контроллере проверку, авторизован ли юзер. Если нет, то редирект на логин.

Comment: а не подскажите как это сделать, я новичек во всем этом

Comment: Я не знаком с KVS. Во фреймворках запрос идет на контроллер. Можно поставить в контроллере проверку, авторизован ли пользователь. Как это проверить - зависит от того как реализована ваша авторизация. Если не авторизован, то делать редирект. Это шаблон решения, а как его реализовать именно в KVS - не могу знать

Comment: Спасибо, но фреймворки не используются в KVS(

Comment: Может есть возможность без использования фрейворков? Подскажите пожалуйста, уже третий день сижу над этой авторизацией, она нужна простенькая

Comment: погугли в сторону "единая точка входа"

Comment: я так думаю, что данный вариант не подойдет, как тогда будет работать  авторизация?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше, если условия файла `check.php` не выполнены, задать HTML странице `display:none` в стилях, а если выполнены, показать HTML.

У вас в `check.php` записана страница, поэтому проще просто взть ее в if конструкцию:

```
if все проверки пройдены успешно (в проверки ваших файлов не вникал поэтому пишу так) 
    вставляйте HTML.  
else  
    Выводите ошибку с просьбой залогинится.
```

Вроде всё.

Comment: Взять в if конструкцию саму ссылку куда редиректит после проверки? 

А как же сделать проверку, кто не залогилился и хочет попасть на сайт, чтобы переводило на авторизацию?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать обычную `if-else` конструкцию на PHP и если авторизация/регестрация не пройдена, то перенаправьте на страницу с регистрацией/авторизацией. Как-то так.